# Responsive Navigation bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
.topnav button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 6px 16px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  font-size: 24px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}
.new_container {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  
}
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
 border-bottom: solid 2px violet;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  border-bottom: solid 2px violet;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}
.icon :hover{
    color: red !important;
    border-bottom: none !important;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    right:10px;
  }
}

.topnav{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 25px auto;

  }

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
        <div class= "new_container">
       <a href="#"><button class="tablinks">Home</button></a>
        <a href="#"><button class="tablinks current">TAB2</button></a>
        <a href="#"><button class="tablinks">TAB3</button></a>
      <a href="#"><button class="tablinks">TAB4</button></a>
       <a href="#"> <button class="tablinks">TAB5</button></a>
       <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick = "myFunction()">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      </a>
        </div>
      </div>
```

This is my code for responsive navigation bar. However when it gets into mobile view I want my elements to display vertically. Instead it gets horizontally aligned. How can i fix that? I want elements to be stacked vertically when screen size reduces to 600px. As i can see the class new_container is being applied how can i remove it when in mobile view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries), [`flex-direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction) property.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
.topnav button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 6px 16px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  font-size: 24px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.new_container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

@media (min-width: 600.1px) {
  .new_container {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  border-bottom: solid 2px violet;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  border-bottom: solid 2px violet;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.icon :hover {
  color: red !important;
  border-bottom: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <div class="new_container">
    <a href="#"><button class="tablinks">Home</button></a>
    <a href="#"><button class="tablinks current">TAB2</button></a>
    <a href="#"><button class="tablinks">TAB3</button></a>
    <a href="#"><button class="tablinks">TAB4</button></a>
    <a href="#"> <button class="tablinks">TAB5</button></a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another example you can [play with the screen dimensions](https://jsfiddle.net/tLwm95b6/1/)